# Failures in spout with no failures in bolts

Tags: apache-storm

Please find below the stats for the Storm topology.

[image: Topology Status]

Relevant info:

- spout1 emits all the tuples to bolt1
- bolt1 executes additional tick tuple (that's why it doesn't match the no of tuple emitted from spout1)

Below are my questions:

1. There are 1059 failures in the spout, whereas there are only 3 failures in one of the downstream bolt
2. The no of tuples emitted from spout1 does not match the no of tuple acked back by bolt1 (I have checked the code, every tuple acks or fails that enters bolt1)

Could anyone help me understand what could be wrong here. My initial guesses are:

- The topology.max.spout.pending is set to 20,000. Could this be causing some kind of buffer overflow. (But if such a overflow occurs, would bolt not report failure?)
- Could there be any network issue that could be causing the tuple to not reach the bolt.

Answer (score 1):

Your tuples are indeed **timing out**.

Look at your average complete latency 49 seconds. Which means that in average each tuple spent 48 seconds inside the topology not being processed by any bolt (if you sum the average execution time by the bolts is less than 1 second... and 49-1=48).

The solution in your case is to **change the number of tuples at the same time inside the topology**. Therefore you should change the `topology.max.spout.pending` to a value lower than 5000. You should try several values, but i think 1000 might do the trick.

### And before you ask, increase the tuple timeout is not solution.

Regarding the missing tuples on bolt one. Are you sure that for each incoming tuple another tuple will be produced?

The only thing you state is that you will ack of fail the tuple, **do you always produce one tuple for each tuple that you receive**?

Answer (score 0):

Complete latency for Spout 1 is 49 seconds even though the execute latency for the bolts is less than a second.  That tells me that you've got a backlog somewhere.  If your timeout is low enough you'll have messages timing out and failing back to the spout which resubmits them making the backlog worse.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. The timeout that I have set is pretty high.

Comment: What is the timeout set to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on/off system stats ? That also includes or excludes tick tuples acked. That way you can get actual tuples number apart from tick tuples. Also you can try increasing the timeout for tuples in order to avoid sending them multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The timeout  for the tuple is already pretty high. So does that mean I should decrease topology.max.spout.pending?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways a tuple can fail. Either, the method `OutputCollector.fail(...)` is called by the user code within a Bolt or a tuple times out. The value "Complete Latency" that is shown for the Spout is an **average** value. So it makes absolutely sense, that most tuples shown as failed ran into a timeout, as only 3 tuples got failed by the user code.

About emitted and acked tuple counts: The reported counts in the UI are not always precise. Even if Storm does count correctly internally, the UI does not show precise values because the counters are collected one by one. Thus, during the collection phase, the counters change in between and the UI does not get an overall consistent snapshot of the count values.

The parameter `topology.max.spout.pending` might be related. Reducing it should lower the chance that a tuple runs into a timeout. Increasing the timeout value itself might not help (as you claim that it is already "pretty high" -- whatever that means).

It is hard to say, if there is a network problem or not though. If there are not error messages in your log, the network should be fine.